# How to embed data studio report in website without giving end user the url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, looker-studio

Is it possible to embed a data studio report into a website without giving users access to the URL?  I have created a data studio report which takes a link-embedded parameter for organization ID.

Example URL: https://datastudio.google.com/embed/reporting/xxx/page/xxx?params=xxx

I will then embed that report in a website for end users to view the report associated with their organization ID.  However, I don't want the user to be able to take the URL and manually edit the organizationId parameter to then be able to see other confidential reports.  If it's not possible to prevent users from seeing the URL from the frontend, is there another way to prevent users from being able to access the same report with someone else's ID parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionid or jwt to check if user asking for the report is the one that can do this. You can guard it as any other route.

Comment: To add JWT authentication, do I need to build a custom community connector and then add the JWT authentication to the isAuthValid() function for a USER_TOKEN?

Comment: How do you authenticate users now?

Comment: Although it hasn't been implemented yet, I was thinking of giving users a JWT token which encrypts their organization ID to send along with the request. Then, the connector can validate the organization ID passed in with the JWT token before connecting to the data source.